# unmodifiable Map still accept adding entries without return UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, unmodifiable

Am trying out adding entry to unmodifiable Map, JVM catch UnsupportedOperationException when adding entry to a subview of original Map, but JVM does not care about direct adding to the original view,  code speaks :

```
ConcurrentMap<String, Integer> origView= new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();
                Map<String,Integer> subView = Collections.unmodifiableMap(origView);
                origView.put("s", 44); // ok
                subView.put("p", 77); // java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

However Documentation of Collections.unmodifiableSortedMap() says :

> Attempts to modify the returned sorted map, whether direct, via its
>   collection views, or via its subMap, headMap, or tailMap views, result
>   in an UnsupportedOperationException.

please lend hand, thanks .

Comment: The returned map has nothing to do with the original map. Of course you can still add things to your original map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "Attempts to modify the **returned** sorted map. ..."

It will only throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` on the `Map` returned from the `unmodifiableMap(...)` call, which does not include the original `Map`.

The `Map` that gets returned from `unmodifiableMap(...)` is *not* the same as the original `Map`.

Answer (score 1):

`Collections.unmodifiableMap()` returns an unmodifiable view of the original map; **it does not change the original map in any way**.  That means that the original map is still modifiable.  You will only get an exception if you try to modify the unmodifiable view.